# Запомнить действия на странице (сортировка, фильтрация)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо при переходе на вторую страницу, запомнить то, что произошло на первой. То есть сортировку таблицы и фильтрацию. Так же, для таблицы сделана пагинация, но сортировка сбрасывается ей. Как можно решить данные две проблемы?

Код контроллера:

```
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string filter=null, int pageNum = 0 )
        {
            ViewBag.filter = filter;
            Repository repository = new Repository();


            ViewData["PageNum"] = pageNum;
            ViewData["ItemsCount"] = (repository.GetMyClass()).Count();
            ViewData["PageSize"] = pageSize;

            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date desc" : "Date";


            var records = (from s in repository.GetMyClass() orderby s.Id select s).Skip(pageSize * pageNum).Take(pageSize);

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Name desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.Created);
                    break;
                case "Date desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.Created);
                    break;
                default:
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.Title);
                    break;
            }



            return View( "_TableRecords",filter == null ? records.ToList() : (records.ToList()).Where(x => x.Title.Contains(filter)));
        }
```

Представление:

```
@using Domain
@model IEnumerable<MyClass>
@using MyProgramm.Helpers


<div>
    <h4>Welcome here!</h4>

    <style>
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="text" name="filter" value="@ViewBag.filter" placeholder="Enter the title..." />
        <span>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </span>
    }

    <table width="350" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"> Id</th>
                <th scope="col"> Parent</th>
                <th scope="col">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
                </th>

                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Created", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (MyClass one in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => one.Id) </th>

                    @if (one.ParentId == null)
                    {
                        <th scope="col">null</th>
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        <th scope="col"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => one.ParentId) </th>
                    }

                    <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => one.Title) </th>
                    <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => one.Description) </th>
                    <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => one.Created) </th>


                </tr>
            }


    </table>

    <p>
        @Html.PagingNavigator((int)Html.ViewData["PageNum"], (int)Html.ViewData["ItemsCount"], (int)Html.ViewData["PageSize"])
    </p>

</div>
```

Paging:

```
    public static class Paging
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PagingNavigator(this HtmlHelper helper, int pageNum,int itemsCount, int pageSize)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (pageNum > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(helper.ActionLink("<", "Index", new { pageNum = pageNum - 1 }));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<"));
            }
            sb.Append(" ");

            int pagesCount =(int) Math.Ceiling((double) itemsCount / pageSize);

            if (pageNum<pagesCount-1)
            {
                sb.Append(helper.ActionLink(">", "Index", new { pageNum = pageNum + 1 }));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(">"));
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository
    {
        private EFContext context;

        public Repository()
        {
            context = new EFContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClass()
        {
            return context.Collection;
        }

        public MyClass GetById(int Id)
        {
            return context.Collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Необходимо при переходе на вторую страницу, запомнить то, что
>   произошло на первой. То есть сортировку таблицы и фильтрацию.

Необходимо сохранить полное состояние поиска (фильтр и сортировку). Можно делать это либо на сервере (сессия), либо клиентом (параметры запроса, куки).

Самый простой и адекватный вариант - засунуть их в GET-параметры ваших пейджинговых ссылок (`PagingNavigator`). *Тогда, помимо вашей конкретной задачи, юзер сможет сделать закладку и сохранить настройки поиска.*

ЗЫ `ViewBag` - хрупкое зло.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74049/discussion-on-answer-by-free-ze------).